# What are these tags called in android?

Tags: android

What are these tags called in android, is there any library for them to use in project?
[tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMJ8K.jpg)

Comment: They are called [chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/).

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for the help you can put that as the answer I can vote up for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many library for tag. you can search using googling or [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/197?sort=created).

or you can make custom tag views.
add use addViews()

for example.

```
LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.main);

Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

myLayout.addView(myButton);
```

Comment: @S T do you know how to create custom tags in android?

Comment: in my answer, you make layout for input tags, and addViews in here.